# Launch configuration FastDateFormat references non-existing project jersey

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to Spring development and so I tried adding the Jersey RESTful api dependency to one of my maven projects. Unfortunately I had to add some remote repository and it seemed to have messed up my launch configurations. Now when I try to launch any old Maven project, I'm always getting this error:

Launch configuration FastDateFormat references non-existing project jersey.

I'm not sure how to fix this in eclipse. Also I am using Spring Tool Suite if that makes in difference. Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Run Configuration` and find the launcher that's giving you trouble. It sounds like it's a maven launcher, so go ahead and fix the `Base directory` to something that does exist. If it is not a maven launcher but a java app launcher, fix the `Project` field

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but the other answer did not apply for me. I'll add what did work for me. Others might benefit from it.

It might be that eclipse thinks the project is of the wrong type.
`Maven > Update Project` can solve this.